# Create a Roslyn analyzer to detect the "Sleep()" method call in a .cs file

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am asking this question in continuity to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829246/create-a-method-call-analyzer-with-roslyn/44847301?noredirect=1#comment76675777_44847301)

I would like to create a roslyn analyzer to detect the use of the sleep method in a .cs file. Could someone please help me correct my code ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace SleepCustomRule
{
 [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class SleepCustomRuleAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "SleepCheck";
    private const string Title = "Sleep function use in forbidden";
    private const string MessageFormat = "Remove this usage of sleep function";
    private const string Description = "Sleep function forbidden";
    private const string Category = "Usage";

    private static readonly ISet<string> Bannedfunctions = ImmutableHashSet.Create("Sleep");

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, 
        DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);


    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);


    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.GenericName);
    }


    private static void AnalyzeNode(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
    {

        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public class Sample
{
public string FooProperty {get; set;}
public void FooMethod()
{
}
 }");

        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
            syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

        var methods = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var node in methods)
        {
            if (node != null)
            {
                // node – is your current syntax node
                // semanticalModel – is your semantical model
                ISymbol symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol ?? semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
                if (symbol.Kind == SymbolKind.Method)
                {
                    string methodName = "sleep";
                    if ((symbol as IMethodSymbol).Name.ToLower() == methodName)
                    {
                        // you find your method
                        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name);
                        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, node.Identifier.GetLocation()));

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

I have those two errors which I could not correct:

1- RegisterSyntaxNodeAction in

```
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.GenericName);
```

2- Assembly in

```
var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
```

3- Besides, I would like to detect the use of the sleep method from a given file not from the var tree I made.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use `context.Node` in your `AnalyzeNode` method. Also, use `context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);`

Comment: You might want to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx

Comment: thank you! 
The error I have in 1 is :
CS0411 The type arguments for method 'AnalysisContext.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction<TLanguageKindEnum>(Action<SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext>, params TLanguageKindEnum[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten has the right answer, change your register, if your error is reffering to after you changed it, you probably missing CSharpLanguage attribute somewhere, please refer to the default analyzer

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

With Kris' suggested solutions, here's how it looks:

```
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
    }


    private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var invocationExpr = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
        var memberAccessExpr = invocationExpr.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

        if (memberAccessExpr?.Name.ToString().ToLower() != "sleep")
            return;

        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationExpr.GetLocation()));
    }
```